# Open Sharepoint Application Page inside ASP.Net web app

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, simplemodal

I have the unusual situation to solve... There is a application page that runs inside SharePoint 2010 with a form to upload some file to a Document Library.

The thing is that this application page needs to be showed on a modal inside my ASPX web app.

I got this running using simplemodal jquery plugin running inside a iframe.

My question is... how can I achieve this functionality considering security questions like a controlled access to this application page? My SharePoint site does not allow anonymous access so I need to figure out how to allow public access only on this page.

Answer (score 0):

I would re-create the page in this asp.net application and then communicate with sharepoint using the client object model or perhaps another approach such a custom webservice (but client model should be ok). I would say that this is the only clean way to achieve your goal.